# getting count in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

can anyone please tell me how to get counts using angular js.
In the application there are several hyperlinks in which some are bold and some are unbold dynamically using condition from iterating using ng-repeat. how can we determine the count of bolded hyperlinks and not bolded hyperlinks

Comment: I and @display_name's answered to your question and you changed it completely. Pls, don't do anything like that. Now our answers are completely invalid. So I suggest you to delete this question and add new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

**Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PaSS4/)**

```
$scope.numberOfBolds = function(x) {
    var bold = 0;
    var unbold = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.stateList, function(item){
        if(item.selected == false) {
            bold++;
        } else {
            unbold++;
        }
    });
    if(x) {
        return bold;
    } else {
        return unbold;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
$scope.boldOnes = $scope.stateList.reduce(function(result,item){
    return result + !item.selected;
},0);
$scope.unboldOnes = $scope.stateList.length - $scope.boldOnes;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/233fU/)

Comment: Actually I print in console. Let me change.

Comment: can we do anything like  `<span ng-if="(state.selected) ? (count+1):count"></span>` within the ng-repeat